# Pulling a URL from a local JSON (Radio Station App)

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I have 4 radio stations in my app and I got the recently played songs pulled from the station JSON but now my issue is I need to get the JSON url from whatever station is currently playing. I have a local JSON that pulls all the info for the station that is selected from the main viewController. Here is the code for my recently played songs viewController. I think I got the code correct but just missing something that is probably small.

```
 guard let urlText = URL(string: currentStation.longDesc)
                else { return }
```

This line of code above I keep getting the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(I have the JSON url for the 30 recently played tracks in the station's LongDescription, thats why it's currentStation.longDesc)

```
var currentStation: RadioStation!
```

The line of code above tells the viewController what station is currently playing.

```
//----------
//MARK: JSON
//----------

//The Initial Response From The JSON
struct Response: Codable {

    var playHistory: Album

}

//The Album Received Which Is An Array Of Song Data
struct Album: Codable {
    var song: [SongData]

}

//The SongData From The PlayHistory Album
struct SongData: Codable{

    var album: String
    var artist: String
    var cover: String
    var duration: String
    var programStartTS: String
    var title: String
}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //1. Create An Array To Store The SongData
    var songs = [SongData]()
    var currentStation: RadioStation!

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        //2. Load The JSON From The Main Bundle

        guard let urlText = URL(string: currentStation.longDesc)
            else { return }


        do{
            //a. Get The Data From The From The File
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlText)

            //b. Decode The Data To Our Structs
            let albumData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)

            //c. Append The Songs Array With The PlayHistory
            albumData.playHistory.song.forEach { songs.append($0) }

            //d. Test Some Data
            print("""
                **The First Album Details**
                Album = \(songs[0].album)
                Artist = \(songs[0].artist)
                Cover = \(songs[0].cover)
                Duration = \(songs[0].duration)
                Start = \(songs[0].programStartTS)
                Title = \(songs[0].title)
                """)

            //3. Load The Data
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }catch{

            print(error)
        }

    }

    //-----------------
    //MARK: UITableView
    //-----------------


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songs.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //1. Create A Cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        //2. Set It's Text
        cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row].title
        cell.artistLabel.text = songs[indexPath.row].artist

        //3. Get The Image
        if let imageURL = URL(string: songs[indexPath.row].cover){

            let request = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { (imageData, response, error) in

                if let error = error{

                    print(error)

                }else{

                    guard let image = imageData else { return }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.songCover.image = UIImage(data: image)
                        cell.setNeedsLayout()
                        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }

                }
            }


            request.resume()
        }

        return cell

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("""
            **Album \(indexPath.row) Selected**
            Album = \(songs[indexPath.row].album)
            Artist = \(songs[indexPath.row].artist)
            Cover = \(songs[indexPath.row].cover)
            Duration = \(songs[indexPath.row].duration)
            Start = \(songs[indexPath.row].programStartTS)
            Title = \(songs[indexPath.row].title)
            """)
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize your `currentStation`?

Comment: @nayem On this view controller it’s right before viewDidLoad.

Comment: It's not the initialization. You just declared the property here.

Comment: @nayem Oh yea, I initialize it on my main ViewController that has my station list. That’s not the issue, I know that works cause I use it on a few other ViewControllers and it pulls in the data that I need pertaining to my local JSON. This issue is it won’t pull in a JSON link from within my local JSON to load my recently played tracks that are on the internet. I just replaced the JSON link in this ViewController with currentStation.longDesc so it would pull in the link instead of having just one link to pull from. I have it pull in the link for the currently playing station.

Comment: @nayem I do this cause I’m reusing the TableView for whatever station is currently playing. I’m still very new to coding so I know I’m missing something. I got it to work perfectly if I just put in 1 link but I need it to pull in the link for the currently playing station so I can show the recently played tracks for that station that is playing.

Comment: Actually I don't get what you're trying to accomplish. But break it down to small tasks. First you need to have the value of **currentStation.londDesc**, which you clearly aren't getting. Because at the time you are accessing that property, it's **nil**. This is the reason you are getting _Unexpectedly found..._. This might be that you aren't passing the correct value to this controller when creating.

Comment: @nayem  I want to have the JSON link pulled from my local JSON instead of a direct link because the station changes depending on what the listener selects. I have 4 stations that each have it’s own local JSON that has: stationImage, stationStreamUrl, stationShortDescription and stationLongDescription. I inserted the recently played JSON link into the stationLongDescription. How can I pull in the stationLongDescription into the link on this code?